# Unexplicable error on newer loaded runtime in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, runtime-error

I have an ASP.NET application

I developed my application pointing as **target Framework the 3.5**. I checked all the projects in the solution and all of them point to 3.5. I checked all the **references** and all of them at the most point to **3.5** (there is some 2.0).

My website is deployed in **IIS 5.0**.

I always receive the following error:

**Version Information:** (Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3615; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618 ):

***Could not load file or assembly 'assembly_name' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.***

```
[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Iceberg.MVC.Data' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +43
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +127
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +142
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Iceberg.MVC.Data' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +613
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +203
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +105
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +178
   System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler..ctor(VirtualDirectory vdir) +163
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectoryInternal(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +53
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectory(VirtualDirectory vdir, VirtualPath virtualDir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +175
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +83
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +261
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +101
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert) +126
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert) +62
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +33
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +40
   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +160
   System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +93
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 1):

IIS 5? If you use Windows 2000, and install .NET 3.5, then this is expected as on 2000, there is no .NET 3.5 SP1. You will have to compile the assemblies against .NET 3.5 RTM. 2000 is end of support, so why not migrate to newer Windows versions?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the IIS instance, try right locating your application in IIS and right click and choose the properties option.  You should see a tab in the window that appears called "ASP.NET", make sure that the selected version is consistent with the one that your application is setup to target.  If you do not see the tab for whatever reason, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/04/17/asp-net-tab-missing.aspx) is a link that may help you out.

Comment: Note that the Framework version will still say 2.0.* for projects targeting 3.5 -> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2008/03/20/running-asp-net-3-5-on-iis.aspx